# Somatória e média tabela sql em java

Tags: sql

Estou tenta problemas com algo acho que até simples, mais não sei qual comando devo executar para fazer isso.

Bom vamos lá:
Tenho uma tabela (vamos chamar de FILMES) ...e essa tabela possui 3 colunas.

**O que eu preciso:**

Preciso somar todos os valores da coluna 2 dessa tabela FILMES e dividir pelo número total de valores. Ou seja, vamos supor que minha segunda coluna tenha 3 valores: 2, 3 e 4.

Preciso somar esses 3 valores e depois dividir por 3.

Ficando assim: (2+3+4)/3.

Eu até sei pegar a soma com o cursor em count. Mas, não sei como faço para recuperar a soma (usar o SUM) em forma de um valor que eu possa estar dividindo pelo total de números.

De quebra precisaria que ele só somasse os itens da coluna 2, cujo o valor da coluna 3 seja 0. Mas, isso posso ver depois, se me ajudarem a recuperar a soma das colunas para eu poder dividir pelo total já seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: João Paulo, acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, veja como deve perguntar aqui no SOPT, depois edite sua pergunta e adicione parte de seu código e da tabela (se tiver), assim será mais fácil te ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples basta você realizar uma projeção, em código já com o critério da terceira coluna ser maior que 0 fica assim:

```
select 
  SUM(nome_coluna2) / COUNT(*)
from 
  Filmes
where
  nome_coluna3 = 0;
```

Qualquer duvida pode comentar a resposta que eu esclareço.

Comment: Criei também um sql fiddle para ilustrar melhor o exemplo, segue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d02bd/2

Comment: Desculpa ai. Não sabia que era assim que funcionava esse forum. Bom, mais de qualquer forma ..estou no aguardo ai do seu edit. Preciso de uma forma de colocar isso em java, ou seja, uma forma de recuperar esse valor. Se eu simplesmente digito isso lá dá errado.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil e prático utilizar a função avg diretamente?

Comment: Select avg(coluna) from tabela , media simples descarta valores nulos